# Add values to global List

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I have the following global List -

```
 public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

    List<string> changes = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> changes = new List<string>();
        }
```

I am trying to add string values to `changes` like so -

```
 protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        DataListItem item = (DataListItem)chk.NamingContainer;

        TextBox txt = (TextBox)DataList1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("aliasTextBox");
        string text = txt.Text;


        changes.Add(text);

        ViewState["array"] = changes;

    }
```

So I am trying to store all changes made in the dataList into `changes` so that when a user clicks -

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> changes = (List<string>)ViewState["array"];

        foreach (string text in changes)
        {

            WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
            ws.WebMethod(text);
        }
    }
```

However when it comes to clicking the button, I get a null reference exception on the - changes.add(text) section. How can I store *all* the values in changes to be available on button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes that you are making to a variable will not persist after the postback. You should save the value of this list 'changes' to a viewstate, session or application so that you can retain the values of the list even after the postback.

Add this code in the `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` event after updating the list

```
ViewState["Somename"]=changes;
```

Add this code in the `Button5_Click` before accessing the list

```
changes= (List<string> )ViewState["Somename"]
```

Comment: This is only retrieving one value and not adding to the list, the list is wiping out everytime I click a checkbox. By using @Anandkumar solution I get a null reference exception?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)**

and change your `List<string> changes = new List<string>();` to `List<string>` `changes =` `null`;

Add this code to your constructor

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 changes = new List<string>();
}
```

Other wise you can use **[ViewState](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp)**

Comment: This is breaking on the line-
changes.Add(text);
With the error-
NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I ave added edits to the question @Anandkumar I am getting a null reference exception.